# Need help in Multithreading Socket programming in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am making a server and client where many clients can connect with the server. Server will ask the clients a question and each client will answer. First to answer correctly will get a mark and server operator will provide new question to all the clients. Server will tell all the clients who has the current highest score. At any time any client can join or leave. My program is pretty much doing all of these but after the server getting the correct answer, for discarding the threads which are getting the answers from client who are waiting to answer, I'm at a loss! Send help!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {
    
    public static LinkedList<clientThread> clientList = new LinkedList<>();
    static int high = 0;
    static String champ = "";
    static Thread t;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        try {           
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(20);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients.");
            new Thread() {
                
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    
                    super.run();
                    Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
                    while(true) {
                        System.out.println("Enter question: ");
                        String qs = consoleInput.nextLine();
            
                        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
                            clientList.get(i).writer.println(qs);
                        }                       

                        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
                            final int temp = i;
                            t = new Thread() {
                                public void run() {
                                    System.out.println(clientList.get(temp).name + " answered: " + clientList.get(temp).reader.nextLine());
                                    System.out.println("Enter 'Y' to mark. 'N' to continue.");
                                    char tempChar = consoleInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
                                    while(tempChar != 'Y' && tempChar != 'y' && tempChar != 'N' && tempChar != 'n') {
                                        System.out.println("Wrong input\nEnter again: ");
                                        tempChar = consoleInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
                                    }
                                    
                                    if(tempChar == 'Y' || tempChar == 'y') {
                                        clientList.get(temp).score++;
                                    }
                                    t.interrupt();
                                    
                                }
                            };
                            t.start();
                        }
                        
                        
                        try {
                            t.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
                            if(high < clientList.get(i).score) {
                                high = clientList.get(i).score;
                                champ = clientList.get(i).name;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
                            clientList.get(i).writer.println("Current math champ: " + champ + "(" + high + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            
            while(true) {
                clientList.add(new clientThread(serverSocket.accept()));
                clientList.peekLast().name = clientList.peekLast().reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(clientList.peekLast().name + " joined.");
                clientList.peekLast().start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry! Can not start the server");
        }
    }
}
```

```
class clientThread extends Thread {
    
    Socket clientSocket;
    Scanner reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    int score;
    String name;
    
    public clientThread(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.reader = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        this.score = 0;
        this.name = "";
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        try {
            clientSocket.isConnected();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Client Left");
        }
        Server.clientList.remove(this);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 20);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
            Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            writer.println(consoleInput.nextLine());
            
            new Thread() {
                
                public void run() {
                    
                    while(true) {
                        
                        System.out.println("Question: " + reader.nextLine());
                        System.out.println("Enter answer: ");
                        writer.println(consoleInput.nextLine());
                        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
                    }
                };
            }.start();          
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `t.join()` and on the last thread referenced by `t` only? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: 1. I don't think `super.run()` inside a `Thread` class will actually accomplish anything. 2. For the problem with client threads, using non-blocking IO seems like it would be the best.

Comment: I think you use too many anonymous classes on the server side (`new Thread() {...}`).  Make those separate classes like you did on the client side, I'm finding your code really difficult to read with all the nested anonymous classes you use.  I think you have some bugs with the way you handle those threads like Hovercraft alludes to but that one method is so cluttered it's hard to be sure what is going on.